# organizing too many arrays Xcode objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode

I am working on an app that is going to have over 50 arrays with over 100 items in each array.  They are used when certain conditions apply.  Is there any way to put these  on different pages and import them as needed.  Here is a sample of my code.

```
if([washington isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]]){

        MKPolygon *polygons = (MKPolygon*) washington;

        CGMutablePathRef mpr = CGPathCreateMutable();

        MKMapPoint *polygonPoints = polygons.points;

        for (int p=0; p < polygons.pointCount; p++){
            MKMapPoint mp = polygonPoints[p];
            if (p == 0)
                CGPathMoveToPoint(mpr, NULL, mp.x, mp.y);
            else
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(mpr, NULL, mp.x, mp.y);
        }

        if(CGPathContainsPoint(mpr , NULL, mapPointAsCGP, TRUE)){

           citiesArray10000 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                @"47.620499&-122.350876&187&Seattle Washington",
                                @"47.673554&-117.416595&1843&Spokane Washington",
                                @"47.252199&-122.459832&&Tacoma Washington",
                                @"45.637236&-122.596516&&Vancouver Washington",
                                @"47.597839&-122.156489&&Bellevue Washington",
                                @"47.385318&122.2169290&&Kent Washington",
                                @"48.003267&-122.174223&&Everett Washington",
                                @"47.476075&-122.192026&&Renton Washington",
                                @"47.308837&-122.336104&&Federal Way Washington",nil;
```

there are 50 states thus 50 if statements and there are going to be 6 or more arrays per state and as many as 100 to 200 entries in each array.
This makes for a very extensive view controller page with all this information.  Is there to put each state's arrays on one page and somehow call them when needed.  Sorry this is probably simple but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the data in plist files stored in your app's bundle. Then you can load each plist file as needed. Don't hardcode that much data in your code. It takes forever to compile and it is hard to read your code.

You might want to write some sort of data model class that encapsulates the data. Then you view controller can create an instance of the data model specifying what data is needed. The data model class can take care of loading the correct data as needed.

Comment: Agreed with rmaddy here. Best if you an use sqlite instead of text-based database. hardcoding data into code is not the way.

Comment: I use a dictionary plist for each state which contained arrays for each category.  Load them when needed. Works great

Answer (score 0):

you can use MVC architecture for your code. Keep only the code that changes the view that will be visible to user such as changing textfields and labels in viewController and write all other functions in different file and call those functions as needed. Like creating points and getting information can be done on other files as model to this view controller.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best practice in this case is to use SQLlite or some other local database to maintain such data.